# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #6](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/6) on Electrical Engineering has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Null]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/6) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4543269995282432).

Answer (score 15):

Thank you to everyone who voted -- whether for me or for one of the other candidates -- and I thank the other candidates for running.

I look forward to serving this community in a new capacity.

Comment: Congrats! on the new role.

Answer (score -11):

Not sure where else to post this!

Thank you a lot to all volunteers, and especially to ***@Null*** in advance for his time and nerves being spent maintaining order on this fantastic free-for-all website!

> and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

I am full of respect for everyone volunteering as moderators on StackExchange, but there is one thing in particular that I would prefer to see changed:

We cannot prevent the *Community* bot from bumping old questions, whose askers have long forgotten about them anyway.

But along the same lines, what we can prevent is people bumping old questions by doing tag changes to them. So if you want to consider my hope:

*Stop bumping old questions by tag changes and minor edits, because a) the askers are gone and b) it is highly distracting for people using the "Active" Questions view.*

Ok, now downvote away :)

Comment: Regarding bumping old questions, I recently learnt from a SO mod that there's a moderator tool for tag merging, which can be used when you wish to remove a bad tag and replace it with something else. He explained that doing so was non-intrusive, as in no bumping.

Comment: What constitutes a "minor edit" can be a matter of opinion, and tag changes aren't necessarily a "minor edit". Old posts are still useful even if the askers are gone because posts are intended to be useful references for all users -- which means they need to be correctly tagged and edited so users can find them and read them easily...

Comment: I do try to space out edits over time to avoid disrupting the front page too much, and as a moderator I can now perform some tag operations (make synonyms and merge) without bumping posts. I also encourage you to edit new posts so we have fewer old posts in need of edits.

Comment: @Null thanks for your replies. I will try to pay more attention to editing new questions. And thanks again for taking on the mod responsibility and good luck

Comment: "the askers are gone" is only a good reason to not try to ask for further clarification in the comments. Afaik, the Stack Exchange model is that all the Q's and associated A's are there to benefit *everyone*, not just the one original asker. So if making changes to a Q or an A improves it for future knowledge-seekers then that's a good thing.